# Itertools without repetition and order

Tags: python, python-itertools

Let's say I have the following list `lst=[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6]`. How can I use itertools to get all possible combinations of 4 numbers? My problem is that there are duplicates which I want to treat as the same subset for example `[1,1,2,3]` is the same as `[1,1,2,3]` even though the 1's are in different positions they represent the same set. Any idea how to proceed?

Example of what I tried:
`listOfCombinations = [x for x in itertools.combination(lst, 5)]`

Answer (score 2):

You can consider maintaining a `set` of your resulting combinations since a `set` doesn't allow duplicates:

```
lst = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6]

res = set()
for c in itertools.combinations(lst, 4):
  res.add(c)

print(res)
# {(2, 5, 6, 6), (2, 4, 4, 6), (2, 4, 4, 5), (1, 4, 4, 5) ...}
```

Or, as *@juanpa.arrivillaga* mentioned, simply

```
res = set(itertools.combinations(lst, 4))
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. That was quite easy. TIL.

Comment: This can just simply be `res = set(itertools.combinations(lst, 4))`